# How to close an open google maps infowindow by clicking marker again

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to close a open google maps infowindow by clicking a marker again. Currently there are only questions about how to close all other infowindows when clicking the map or other markers.

How to close an open google maps infowindow by clicking the same marker again? Currently I can only close an infowindow by clicking the cross on the top right corner of the infowindow.

This is what I tried but it doesn't even open the infowindow:

```
    EncoreMarker.addListener('click', function () {
        if (EncoreInfoCard.open) {
            EncoreInfoCard.close(map, EncoreMarker);
        }
        else {
            EncoreInfoCard.open(map, EncoreMarker);
        }               
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code won't work because `open` is a function that opens the `InfoWindow`, not a `boolean` that tells whether it is open or not.

This works for me:

```
EncoreMarker.addListener('click', function () {
    // create a custom property of the InfoWindow, defaults to a value that evaluates as false
    if (EncoreInfoCard.isOpen) { 
        EncoreInfoCard.close(map, EncoreMarker);
        EncoreInfoCard.isOpen = false;
    }
    else {
        EncoreInfoCard.open(map, EncoreMarker);
        EncoreInfoCard.isOpen = true;
    }               
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/na26veh0/5/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
// When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.
// When the user clicks the makrer again, the info window closes.

function initMap() {
  var uluru = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });

  var EncoreInfoCard = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<b>This is a Test</b>"
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(EncoreInfoCard, 'closeclick', function() {
    EncoreInfoCard.isOpen = false;
  });
  var EncoreMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });

  EncoreMarker.addListener('click', function() {
    if (EncoreInfoCard.isOpen) {
      EncoreInfoCard.close(map, EncoreMarker);
      EncoreInfoCard.isOpen = false;
    } else {
      EncoreInfoCard.open(map, EncoreMarker);
      EncoreInfoCard.isOpen = true;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: This will *fail* if you close the InfoWindow using the close button.